# Can Synapse launcher be installed in Debian?

Tags: debian, synapse

I am thinking of changing from Linux Mint Cinnamon to Linux Mint Debian Cinnamon, but Synapse launcher is something I can't work without. It doesn't seem to be available in Debian.

Does anyone know if it is possible to install it and use all the features it offers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go here and if in North America click one of the links if in another country click the closest link. https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/synapse/download

Answer (score 0):

It is available in Debian unstable here, so should be available in Linux Mint eventually, if it is not already.

```
apt-cache policy synapse
synapse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.2.99.1-1
  Version table:
     0.2.99.1-1 0
         50 tor+http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
```

If it not currently available in Linux Mint Debian Edition, it should be easy to backport if you want to do so.

The build dependencies are:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9),
intltool,
pkg-config,
valac,
libzeitgeist-2.0-dev,
libdbus-glib-1-dev,
libgtk-3-dev,
libgee-0.8-dev,
libjson-glib-dev,
libkeybinder-3.0-dev,
libnotify-dev
```

which are satisfied even on jessie. I was able to build and run it on jessie with no trouble.